# Get value after decimal separator from floating point number in Delphi

Tags: delphi, formatting

How to get value after decimal separator for given floating point number?

```
Number: 129.60
Expected result: 60
```

Comment: `FormatFloat` returns a decimal value. Please elaborate exactly what you mean. Show code and output. Explain why the output does not match your expectation.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong expressed question. I need value after decimal separator. If we have number 129.60, I need 60.

Comment: OK, then Andreas has you covered. That's nothing to do with `FormatFloat` though. Please can you edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: The edit doesn't help much. You haven't stated a context. I presume you have a floating point value. Please make that context clear.

Answer (score 15):

Just use the `Frac` function.

For instance, `Frac(3.14)` equals `0.14`. Of course, as soon as you have got rid of the integer part of the number, you can use any method of your choice to make a string out of it, like `FloatToStr`, `FormatFloat`, `Format`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
var
  abobrinha, Expected : real;
begin
  abobrinha := 129.60;
  Expected := abobrinha - trunc(abobrinha);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your number in a `string`, and want to have the result in a `string` too, than you can do it without converting to a number. If not, see Andreas answer.

```
i := Pos( DecimalSeparator, value );
if i > 0 then
  result := Copy( value, i + 1, Length( value ) - i )
else
  result := '';
```

Comment: This will fail for a string like `1.2e1`.